# Find sample size of a regression with calculated matrix

Tags: statistics, regression, parameter-estimation, linear-regression

The question is given like the following:

> [image: question - matrix form]

And I'm wondering how can I find the sample size from these calculated metrics? Also, I'm not sure how I can find the estimator for the variance.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the design matrix has the following form 
$$
X = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & x_{11} & x_{22} \\
1 & x_{12} &  x_{22}\\
: & : & : \\
1 & x_{1n} & x_{2n}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
hence the $X_{11}$ entry of $X'X$ is 
$$
(1\quad 1\cdots 1)
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
:\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
=\sum_{i=1}^n 1 = n .
$$
Hence, your sample size is $30$.

And for the unbiased estimator of the variance, $Var(\epsilon) = \sigma^2$, you should compute $MSE = SSE/(n-2)$, where 
$$
SSE = Y'Y - \hat{\beta}X'Y,
$$
and $\hat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y$.